# How to download whole internal memory of Nokia Lumia (Windows Phone 8.1) to computer?

Tags: lumia, recovery

Good morning,

i get Nokia Lumia 532 for file recovery process service (user deleted important contacts). I had do it with Android phones, but never with Windows Phones. So my question is - is there a way to download whole internal memory of Windows Phone device to the computer?

Which tools should I use?

Thank you,

Comment: As of I know you can't unless you get access to File System which Microsoft doesn't allowed in Windows Phones. However, you can check these. https://youtu.be/j03Q6yEi6K0 http://tinyurl.com/hnxdab9 http://tinyurl.com/gmg9drc try at your own risk. We've neither tried nor tested.

Comment: Hi @Ravimallya, thank you for your answer. I read it carefully, and tried all the methods, but nothing works (Windows Phone Internals is not working with this Lumia model). Thank you once again and best regards.

Comment: You could try JTAG. It's supposed to be disabled on retail phones but I've seen people do it with earlier-model Lumias (520, 920, etc.). Never tried with a 532. It requires hardware, and opening up the phone, but if you get it working it'll give you full access to the phone's storage media. (Of course, if the phone is encrypted, this won't help, so hopefully it isn't.)